# Query that returns comma separated list and allows to search inside it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I have `MainTable` with 2 fields: `MAIN_ID` and `DESCRIPTION` and `SeoncdaryTable` with 2 fields: `MAIN_ID` (`FK` to `MainTable`) and `EXTRA_INFO`.

I would like to have a query that returns one record per `MainTable` record (`select * from MainTable`) plus having another result that shows me in comma separated fashion all the records of `SecondaryTable` (of course matcihing the `MAIN_ID`).

Moreover I would like in the `WHERE` condition to be able to filter for `SecondaryTable` fields.

Example:

`MainTable`:

`MAIN_ID`, `DESCRIPTION`

1, One

2, Two

3, Three

4, Four

Secondary Table

MAIN_ID; EXTRA_INFO;

1; ALPHA

1; BETA

1; GAMMA

3; BETA

4; ALPHA

4; GAMMA

and I want to query all the records where secondary table contains GAMMA, the expected results are

1; One; ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA

4, Four; ALPHA, GAMMA

how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @MainTable table (MAIN_ID int identity, [DESCRIPTION] varchar(10));
insert into @MainTable values('One'),('Two'),('Three'),('Four'),('Five');

declare @SecondaryTable table (MAIN_ID int, EXTRA_INFO varchar(10));
insert into @SecondaryTable values
(1, 'ALPHA'), (1, 'BETA'), (1, 'GAMMA'), (3, 'BETA'), (4, 'ALPHA'), (4, 'GAMMA');

select MT.MAIN_ID,
       MT.[DESCRIPTION],
       stuff((select ', '+ST.EXTRA_INFO
              from @SecondaryTable as ST
              where MT.MAIN_ID = ST.MAIN_ID
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as EXTRA_INFO
from @MainTable as MT
where MT.MAIN_ID in (select MAIN_ID      
                     from @SecondaryTable
                     where EXTRA_INFO = 'GAMMA')
```

Comment: Never heard about stuff. Thanks for the very complete reply.

Comment: @user - Stuff is only there to remove the extra `, ` that is added before the first `EXTRA_INFO`. You could use `substring` or `right` instead. The concatenation trick is done by `for xml path('')`.

Answer (score 0):

ave you tried using `STUFF` this command stuffs all the result rows into a single column, here you can provide the delimiter of your choice.

Comment: I think not. Sounds good but... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx